# Can't Reach Printer on Same Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer

I'm trying to configure my HP printer using an IP address rather than WSD, because WSD constantly tells me my printer is offline and won't print until sitting on a document for 15+ minutes. It's frustrating, so I'm trying to reconfigure my printer device by changing it to an IP based configuration.

The problem is that my laptop reports 192.168.0.3 is an unreachable host. Why?

Does it make a difference that we're using a Spectrum provided router? Do they block ping?

### Laptop

- IP Address: 192.168.0.8
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

### Printer

- IP Address: 192.168.0.3
- Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
- Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

**Laptop ipconfig settings**

[image: ping results]

**Printer Wireless Configuration**

[image: printer settings]

### Edit

I logged into the default gateway, and I'm a little confused; it says it's a "Wireless Modem". Does this function as a router also, or is that my problem? I've always used separate modem and router devices, so I'm wondering if the Ubee Wireless Modem provided by Spectrum / Time Warner Cable does not function as a router.

https://www.ubeeinteractive.com/?product=dvw32cb-advanced-wireless-voice-gateway

Answer (score 0):

Stupid Resolution. After logging into the router, I noticed that the DHCP client list lacked 192.168.0.3 (the printer), even though the printer reported that it was connected.

After disabling the printer's wireless, then re-enabling it, 192.168.0.3 showed up in the DHCP client list. After this, I was able to configure my ip based printer.

Turned printer Wireless on and off again.